# Best way to manage a collection of pointers to derived objects

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

I'm new to c++ coming from c#. The following code is not working and I'm not sure what it needs. Any insight to help me understand why it isn't working and what the appropriate changes it should have would be appreciated.

```
// GamePlayScreen derives from ScreenBase
std::unique_ptr<GameplayScreen> m_game(new GameplayScreen());

// MenuScreen derives from ScreenBase
std::unique_ptr<MenuScreen> m_menu(new MenuScreen());

// PauseScreen derives from ScreenBase
std::unique_ptr<PauseScreen> m_pause(new PauseScreen());        

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ScreenBase>*> screens;

screens.push_back(&m_game); // this gets the error
```

I get compile error:

> C2284 "cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty> *' to 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty> *&&'

If I comment out the last line, it compiles fine.

Basically, I would like to have a collection of the derived items (or rather pointers to them). I've tried various ways of 'pointing and/or referencing' the parameter and various ways of establishing the T in `vector<T>` but the solution eludes me.

Comment: @JesseGood has an answer for how to get the type you want, **if** stowing a transfer-of-ownership of the unique pointer is your goal.  @Alf suggests using `shared_ptr` which is preferable most of the time.  This article may be of interest: http://hostilefork.com/2009/07/10/smart-pointer-casting-study/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm reading a lot of:

> ...you probably want shared_ptrs...

I would encourage people to default to `unique_ptr` when unsure.  Plopping down `shared_ptr` without memory ownership design is exactly what leads to cyclic memory leaks.

Yes, you can create cyclic memory leaks with `unique_ptr` too.  However my experience has been that when `unique_ptr` is used it encourages the designer to understand who owns what as the design evolves, making cyclic memory leaks less likely, and easier to debug when they do occur.

And if during this design process, the designer discovers that shared ownership semantics is actually needed, then by all means, reach for `shared_ptr` (and probably `weak_ptr` too to break those cycles).

Finally, bind your raw pointers to your smart pointers as quickly as possible.  The following is a compilable sketch of the OP's problem which follows best practices:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

// A general purpose factory function for unique_ptrs
// Feel free to make this factory function more specific to your domain
template <class T, class ...Args>
typename std::enable_if
<
    !std::is_array<T>::value,
    std::unique_ptr<T>
>::type
make_ScreenParts(Args&& ...args)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}

// Your class hierarchy
struct ScreenBase
{
    // Don't forget to make your destructors virtual
    virtual ~ScreenBase() = default;
};

// Future-proof your code with typedef's
// If / when you need to switch smart pointer types
//  or container types, you'll thank yourself
typedef std::unique_ptr<ScreenBase> ScreenPtr;
typedef std::vector<ScreenPtr> ScreenContainer;

struct GameplayScreen
    : public ScreenBase
{
};

struct MenuScreen
    : public ScreenBase
{
};

struct PauseScreen
    : public ScreenBase
{
};

int main()
{
    // raw pointers never exposed here...
    ScreenContainer screens;
    screens.push_back(make_ScreenParts<GameplayScreen>());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this input. Although very inexperienced & lacking knowledge, much of what I read tells me that well written c++ code hardly uses raw pointers anymore and this is what you appear to be corroborating. I appreciate your code snippet and have gleened some understanding from it but I haven't a clue what to place in the "...args" sections to make it compile but I kind of recognize the point you are conveying.. Thanks.

Comment: @SteveH: It may be that your compiler does not implement variadic templates yet (the ... stuff).  If it did, the above should just compile and work, without leaking.  If that is the case, you could implement several `make_ScreenParts` overloads:  one taking zero arguments - that's the one used in this example, one taking one argument, one taking two arguments, etc.  In general you would use it with: `make_ScreenParts<GameplayScreen>(arg1, arg2, arg3)`, where `GameplayScreen` has a constructor taking `arg1`, `arg2` and `arg3`.

Comment: understood. I was able to get it to compile by simplifying it to remove the args for now. I'll work those out when I need them. I did, however, need to add a definition for <code>ScreenBase::~ScreenBase(){};</code> to keep the compiler from complaining.  I have Scott Meyers book and understand the reason for the virtual destructor now too. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

no compiler to validate here, but I'm sure you can:

```
// GamePlayScreen derives from ScreenBase
std::shared_ptr<GameplayScreen> m_game(new GameplayScreen());

// MenuScreen derives from ScreenBase
std::shared_ptr<MenuScreen> m_menu(new MenuScreen());

// PauseScreen derives from ScreenBase
std::shared_ptr<PauseScreen> m_pause(new PauseScreen());        

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ScreenBase>> screens;

screens.push_back( m_game );
```

Like @cheers-and-hth-alf said, you probably want shared pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the last two lines as follows:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ScreenBase>> screens;

screens.push_back(std::move(m_game));
```

I removed the asterisk because you probably wanted a vector of `unique_ptr`, not a vector of pointers to a `unique_ptr`. Also, `unique_ptr` as its name implies, means that only one `unique_ptr` can have ownership at one time, so you need to explicity `std::move` it to transfer ownership.

Comment: names like `m_game` indicate member variables. it seems doubtful that the intention is to move the pointers out of the member variables.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: That's true, however, it is somewhat unclear what the purpose is.

Answer (score 1):

Use `shared_ptr` instead of `unique_ptr`, since you're going to reference those screen objects from many places.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But after replacing all the 'unique-ptr's with 'shared_pter's, the problem is still there. same compile error.

Comment: @Steve: sorry, i didn't see the declaration of your vector, but now I see it. don't make it a vector of raw pointers to smart pointers. make it a vector of smart pointers.

Comment: You are right, it is a different fail code but similar:  error C2664: 'void std::vector<_Ty>::push_back(std::shared_ptr<ScreenBase> *&&)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::shared_ptr<_Ty> *' to 'std::shared_ptr<_Ty> *&&'

Comment: @hth - alf, By removing the raw pointer * and switching to shared_ptr, it does compile. But now screens[0] seems to only have access to base class (ScreenBase) items and not derived class items (gameplayScreen). Shouldn't I be able to go screens[0]->… and see derived class items?

Comment: the screens vector is of the base type - like a Collection<ScreenBase> in c# would have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a situation where you want to manage various screens with specific types, but also have another list of the screens as the base type, so that you can do certain operations on all the screens without having to know the details of the specific types of screens.

I think in this case you just want a raw pointer:

```
// GamePlayScreen derives from ScreenBase
std::unique_ptr<GameplayScreen> m_game(new GameplayScreen());

// MenuScreen derives from ScreenBase
std::unique_ptr<MenuScreen> m_menu(new MenuScreen());

// PauseScreen derives from ScreenBase
std::unique_ptr<PauseScreen> m_pause(new PauseScreen());        

std::vector<ScreenBase*> screens;

screens.push_back(&*m_game);
```

You just have to be careful not to leave the pointers in screens dangling if you destroy the screens.

Comment: This does compile, but then screens[0]-> only accesses base class items. I would like to access derived class items too. How would I set it up to do that?

Comment: @SteveH:  For each member function you want to access via a (smart or raw) pointer to the base, the base must have a *virtual* member function.  The compiler will then ensure that the *most derived* version of that member function is called.  Member data can not be made virtual like this.  However you can write virtual member functions in the base that access member data only in the derived.  And in this case, the base virtual member accessor should either be pure virtual (` = 0`), or have some default implementation that does not require access to the derived member data.